# SASS script to generate Pygments / Rogue stylesheet output

Tags: sass

I've written some SASS code to generate a [Pygments syntax highlighter style sheet](http://pygments.org/) (which are, by extension, compatible with [Rouge](http://rouge.jneen.net/)). Such a stylesheet is normally generated by the `pygmentize` command-line tool from [predefined styles defined in Python classes](https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/pygments-main/src/default/pygments/styles/), the code below reflects the [Pygments token hierarchy](https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/pygments-main/src/7941677dc77d4f2bf0bbd6140ade85a9454b8b80/pygments/token.py#lines-56:83), recording the relationship to [the CSS classes used](https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/pygments-main/src/7941677dc77d4f2bf0bbd6140ade85a9454b8b80/pygments/token.py#lines-124:213) so we can output those classes.

The idea is that you define a nested map to set any of a foreground, background or border color, and if italics, bold or underlying should be enabled. For example, encoding the [`friendly` style](https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/pygments-main/src/7941677dc77d4f2bf0bbd6140ade85a9454b8b80/pygments/styles/friendly.py) packaged with Pygments, becomes:

```css
// Pygments "friendly" theme
$highlight-style: (
  comment: (color: #60a0b0, italic: true) (
    preproc: (#007020),
    special: (color: #60a0b0, bgcolor: #fff0f0),
  ),
  error: (border: #ff0000),
  generic: null (
    deleted: #a00000,
    error: #ff0000,
    heading: (color: #000080, bold: true),
    inserted: #00A000,
    output: #808080,
    prompt: (color: #c65d09, bold: true),
    subheading: (color: #800080, bold: true),
    traceback: #0040D0,
  ),
  highlight: (bgcolor: #ffffcc),
  keyword: (color: #007020, bold: true) (
    pseudo: #007020,
    type: #902000,
  ),
  literal: null (
    number: #40a070,  // with float, hex, integer, integer.long and oct subtypes
    string: #4070a0 (
      // backtick, char, double, heredoc, single all inheriting
      doc: (color: #4070a0, italic: true),
      escape: (color: #4070a0, bold: true),
      interpol: (color: #70a0d0, italic: true),
      other: #c65d09,
      regex: #235388,
      symbol: #517918,
    ),
  ),
  name: null (
    attribute: #4070a0,
    builtin: #007020,
    class: (color: #0e84b5, bold: true),
    constant: #60add5,
    decorator: (color: #555555, bold: true),
    entity: (color: #d55537, bold: true),
    exception: #007020,
    function: #06287e,
    label: (color: #002070, bold: true),
    namespace: (color: #0e84b5, bold: true),
    tag: (color: #062873, bold: true),
    variable: #bb60d5,  // with class, global and instance subtypes same
  ),
  operator: #666666 (
    word: (color: #007020, bold: true),
  ),
  text: null (
    whitespace: #bbbbbb,
  ),
);
```

The Python model is a little more sophisticated in that the 6 different properties are individually inherited; you could set a color for `String` then only add that `String.Escape` should use italics in addition. This then requires support for *not italic*, to disable the boolean options again. I opted for not making my version as advanced, you inherit all properties or define the set anew for child tokens.

This produces:

```css
/* Pygments / rouge source code highlight styles */
.highlight .c { color: #60a0b0; font-style: italic; /* comment */ }
.highlight .ch { color: #60a0b0; font-style: italic; /* comment.hashbang */ }
.highlight .cm { color: #60a0b0; font-style: italic; /* comment.multiline */ }
.highlight .cp { color: #007020; /* comment.preproc */ }
.highlight .cpf { color: #60a0b0; font-style: italic; /* comment.preprocfile */ }
.highlight .c1 { color: #60a0b0; font-style: italic; /* comment.single */ }
.highlight .cs { color: #60a0b0; background-color: #fff0f0; /* comment.special */ }
.highlight .err { border: 1px solid #ff0000; /* error */ }
.highlight .gd { color: #a00000; /* generic.deleted */ }
.highlight .ge { font-style: italic; /* generic.emph */ }
.highlight .gr { color: #ff0000; /* generic.error */ }
.highlight .gh { color: #000080; font-weight: bold; /* generic.heading */ }
.highlight .gi { color: #00A000; /* generic.inserted */ }
.highlight .go { color: #808080; /* generic.output */ }
.highlight .gp { color: #c65d09; font-weight: bold; /* generic.prompt */ }
.highlight .gs { font-weight: bold; /* generic.strong */ }
.highlight .gu { color: #800080; font-weight: bold; /* generic.subheading */ }
.highlight .gt { color: #0040D0; /* generic.traceback */ }
.highlight .hll { background-color: #ffffcc; /* highlight */ }
.highlight .k { color: #007020; font-weight: bold; /* keyword */ }
.highlight .kc { color: #007020; font-weight: bold; /* keyword.constant */ }
.highlight .kd { color: #007020; font-weight: bold; /* keyword.declaration */ }
.highlight .kn { color: #007020; font-weight: bold; /* keyword.namespace */ }
.highlight .kp { color: #007020; /* keyword.pseudo */ }
.highlight .kr { color: #007020; font-weight: bold; /* keyword.reserved */ }
.highlight .kt { color: #902000; /* keyword.type */ }
.highlight .m { color: #40a070; /* literal.number */ }
.highlight .mb { color: #40a070; /* literal.number.bin */ }
.highlight .mf { color: #40a070; /* literal.number.float */ }
.highlight .mh { color: #40a070; /* literal.number.hex */ }
.highlight .mi { color: #40a070; /* literal.number.integer */ }
.highlight .il { color: #40a070; /* literal.number.integer.long */ }
.highlight .mo { color: #40a070; /* literal.number.oct */ }
.highlight .s { color: #4070a0; /* literal.string */ }
.highlight .sa { color: #4070a0; /* literal.string.affix */ }
.highlight .sb { color: #4070a0; /* literal.string.backtick */ }
.highlight .sc { color: #4070a0; /* literal.string.char */ }
.highlight .dl { color: #4070a0; /* literal.string.delimiter */ }
.highlight .sd { color: #4070a0; font-style: italic; /* literal.string.doc */ }
.highlight .s2 { color: #4070a0; /* literal.string.double */ }
.highlight .se { color: #4070a0; font-weight: bold; /* literal.string.escape */ }
.highlight .sh { color: #4070a0; /* literal.string.heredoc */ }
.highlight .si { color: #70a0d0; font-style: italic; /* literal.string.interpol */ }
.highlight .sx { color: #c65d09; /* literal.string.other */ }
.highlight .sr { color: #235388; /* literal.string.regex */ }
.highlight .s1 { color: #4070a0; /* literal.string.single */ }
.highlight .ss { color: #517918; /* literal.string.symbol */ }
.highlight .na { color: #4070a0; /* name.attribute */ }
.highlight .nb { color: #007020; /* name.builtin */ }
.highlight .bp { color: #007020; /* name.builtin.pseudo */ }
.highlight .nc { color: #0e84b5; font-weight: bold; /* name.class */ }
.highlight .no { color: #60add5; /* name.constant */ }
.highlight .nd { color: #555555; font-weight: bold; /* name.decorator */ }
.highlight .ni { color: #d55537; font-weight: bold; /* name.entity */ }
.highlight .ne { color: #007020; /* name.exception */ }
.highlight .nf { color: #06287e; /* name.function */ }
.highlight .fm { color: #06287e; /* name.function.magic */ }
.highlight .nl { color: #002070; font-weight: bold; /* name.label */ }
.highlight .nn { color: #0e84b5; font-weight: bold; /* name.namespace */ }
.highlight .nt { color: #062873; font-weight: bold; /* name.tag */ }
.highlight .nv { color: #bb60d5; /* name.variable */ }
.highlight .vc { color: #bb60d5; /* name.variable.class */ }
.highlight .vg { color: #bb60d5; /* name.variable.global */ }
.highlight .vi { color: #bb60d5; /* name.variable.instance */ }
.highlight .vm { color: #bb60d5; /* name.variable.magic */ }
.highlight .o { color: #666666; /* operator */ }
.highlight .ow { color: #007020; font-weight: bold; /* operator.word */ }
.highlight .w { color: #bbbbbb; /* text.whitespace */ }
```

The idea is that you can now use SASS color functions to generate a style from a base color scheme.

This is the SASS partial that produces the output:

```css
// Pygment / Rouge style generation

$highlight-selector: ".highlight";

// Define styles for the class hierarchy as a nested map;
// values are argument lists for the pygments-rule mixin
// Nested elements take the parent style if not set to null
$highlight-style: () !default;
$highlight-style-defaults: (
    generic: null (
        emph: (italic: true),
        strong: (bold: true),
    ),
);
$highlight-style-classes: (
    comment: 'c' (
        hashbang: 'ch',
        multiline: 'cm',
        preproc: 'cp',
        preprocfile: 'cpf',
        single: 'c1',
        special: 'cs',
    ),
    escape: 'esc',
    error: 'err',
    generic: null (
        deleted: 'gd',
        emph: 'ge',
        error: 'gr',
        heading: 'gh',
        inserted: 'gi',
        output: 'go',
        prompt: 'gp',
        strong: 'gs',
        subheading: 'gu',
        traceback: 'gt',
    ),
    highlight: 'hll',
    keyword: 'k' (
        constant: 'kc',
        declaration: 'kd',
        namespace: 'kn',
        pseudo: 'kp',
        reserved: 'kr',
        type: 'kt'
    ),
    literal: 'l' (
        date: 'ld',
        number: 'm' (
            bin: 'mb',
            float: 'mf',
            hex: 'mh',
            integer: 'mi' (
                long: 'il'
            ),
            oct: 'mo',
        ),
        string: 's' (
            affix: 'sa',
            backtick: 'sb',
            char: 'sc',
            delimiter: 'dl',
            doc: 'sd',
            double: 's2',
            escape: 'se',
            heredoc: 'sh',
            interpol: 'si',
            other: 'sx',
            regex: 'sr',
            single: 's1',
            symbol: 'ss',
        ),
    ),
    name: 'n' (
        attribute: 'na',
        builtin: 'nb' (
            pseudo: 'bp',
        ),
        class: 'nc',
        constant: 'no',
        decorator: 'nd',
        entity: 'ni',
        exception: 'ne',
        function: 'nf' (
            magic: 'fm'
        ),
        label: 'nl',
        namespace: 'nn',
        other: 'nx',
        property: 'py',
        tag: 'nt',
        variable: 'nv' (
            class: 'vc',
            global: 'vg',
            instance: 'vi',
            magic: 'vm',
        ),
    ),
    operator: 'o' (
        word: 'ow',
    ),
    other: 'x',
    punctuation: 'p',
    text: null (
        whitespace: 'w',
    ),
);

@function highlight-map-deep-get($map, $keys...) {
    $value: null;
    @each $key in $keys {
        $entry: map-get($map, $key);
        @if $entry != null {
            $value: if(type-of($entry) == list, nth($entry, 1), $entry);
            $map: if(type-of($entry) == list and length($entry) > 1, nth($entry, 2), null) or ();
        } @else {
            @return null;
        }
    }
    @return $value;
}

@function highlight-map-merge($parent-map, $child-map) {
    $result: $parent-map;
    @each $key, $value in $child-map {
        $resultvalue: map-get($result, $key);
        @if not map-has-key($result, $key) {
            $result: map-merge($result, ($key: $value));
        } @else {
            $resultvalue1: if(type-of($resultvalue) == list, nth($resultvalue, 1), $resultvalue);
            $value1: if(type-of($value) == list, nth($value, 1), $value) or $resultvalue1;
            $resultmap: if(type-of($resultvalue) == list and length($resultvalue) > 1, nth($resultvalue, 2), null);
            $valuemap: if(type-of($value) == list and length($value) > 1, nth($value, 2), null);
            @if $resultmap and $valuemap {
                $valuemap: highlight-map-merge($resultmap or (), $valuemap or ());
            };
            $result: map-merge($result, ($key: $value1 $valuemap));
        }
    }
    @return $result;
}

@function to-dotted-string($list) {
  $result: null;

  @for $i from 1 through length($list) {
    $e: nth($list, $i);
    $result: if($i != length($list), "#{$result}#{$e}.", "#{$result}#{$e}");
  }

  @return $result;
}


@mixin highlight-rule($color: null, $bold: false, $italic: false, $underline: false, $bgcolor: null, $border: null) {
    @if $color     { color: $color; }
    @if $bold      { font-weight: bold; }
    @if $italic    { font-style: italic; }
    @if $underline { text-decoration: underline; }
    @if $bgcolor   { background-color: $bgcolor; }
    @if $border    { border: 1px solid $border; }
}

@mixin highlight-class($map, $values, $path: (), $parentvalue: null) {
    @each $key, $value in $map {
        $classname: nth($value, 1);
        $fullpath: append($path, $key);
        $styleargs: null;
        @if $classname != null {
            $styleargs: highlight-map-deep-get($values, $fullpath...) or $parentvalue or ();
            @if $styleargs != null and length($styleargs) > 0 {
                .#{$classname} {
                    @include highlight-rule($styleargs...);
                    /* #{to-dotted-string($fullpath)} */
                }
            }
        }
        @if length($value) > 1 {
            // recursion to subelelements
            @include highlight-class(nth($value, 2), $values, $fullpath, $styleargs);
        };
    };
};

/* Pygments / rouge source code highlight styles */
#{$highlight-selector} {
    @include highlight-class(
        $highlight-style-classes,
        highlight-map-merge($highlight-style-defaults, $highlight-style)
    );
};
```

As this is my first piece of SASS mixin code, I'd like to have feedback on style and techniques used.